# How to change the a string to a integer in a data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I got a TypeError when I tried mapping the values of column is data frame which where strings to integers.How to solve that type error?

```
for dataset in train_df:

     dataset['Embarked'] = dataset['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2} ).astype(int)
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

in

```
      1 for dataset in train_df:
----> 2     dataset['Embarked'] = dataset['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2} ).astype(int)
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Did you map all the possible strings? What does `dataset['Embarked'].unique()` return?

Comment: I think there are some non matched values, so in output is NaN, so need `dataset['Embarked'] = dataset['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2} ).fillna(-1).astype(int)` or use `dataset['Embarked'] = dataset['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2} ).astype('Int64')` if use `pandas 0.24+`

Comment: Just tested: `pd.to_numeric(dataset['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2}))` works.